# Crystal report not working after setup installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I know there is already some topics related to my issue but i did'nt get any help from that.
I have created a windows application using c# . I created setup file of that project and installed in client system. Everything is working fine except crystal reports. Kindly view my error below and guide me if there is some problem in creation of setupfile.

---

### Error

```
Error::System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'

   at LpuDeExam.SeatingPlan.InitializeComponent()

   at LpuDeExam.SeatingPlan..ctor()



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)

   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)

   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

   at LpuDeExam.MainMenu.listView1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
---------------------------
OK   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This error happens only on client machine?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should download and install proper (I think 13.0.2000.0) "Crystal Reports Runtime" version on the machine you run your application.

If your application is build in 32-bit architecture, please download from this location:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_3.msi
otherwise (64-bit) please use the link below:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_3.msi

The links originate from this discussion: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3172181

I hope it will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not looking deep enough into the subject -  I think the links that were given might not have been the proper ones.

If you could and if your application is built upon **.NET Framework 4**, please download redist runtime package from this link:

**MSI 32 bit**
**http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0.zip**

(taken from site: **http://scn.sap.com/thread/1903613**)

On the machine you develop your application, please uninstall the CR you downloaded earlier, reboot the computer and then try to install (with admin rights if possible) the file obtained from the above link.

I hope it will help.

As for the question about setup file, as far as I remember from my experience with app that was using CR for VS 2010 .NET 4.0 I had to download proper redist package first, install it separately on client machine, and then install and use my application, although I don't have much experience in building installation setup packages :)